# .AsSpan ArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

can smebody explain why .AsSpan thorws an ArrayTypeMismatchException while creating a new ReadOnlySpan doesn't?

```
SomeMethod(Foo data) {
  IPoint[] tmp = (IPoint[])data.Points; // data.Points is OwnPoint[] (class OwnPoint : IPoint)
  //ReadOnlySpan<IPoint> pointsSpan = ((IPoint[])tmp).AsSpan(); //  System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.'
  //ReadOnlySpan<IPoint> pointsSpan = tmp.AsSpan(); //  System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.'
  ReadOnlySpan<IPoint> pointsSpan = new ReadOnlySpan<IPoint>(tmp);// works
  Bar(pointsSpan);
}

public void Bar(ReadOnlySpan<IPoint> pts) {
    // ...
}
```

what am I missing? thought that .AsSpan did the same as creating a new one.

Comment: What is the concrete type of `data.Points`?

Comment: see code comment: // data.Points is OwnPoint[] (class OwnPoint : IPoint)

Comment: Simply, because [`Span<T>` has that check](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Span.cs,37) and [`ReadOnlySpan` does not](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ReadOnlySpan.cs,37). That's probably because with array variance it's always safe to read elements, but it's not always safe to insert them. `ReadOnlySpan<T>` doesn't let you write elements, so there's no need for the check

Comment: E.g. with array variance, you can write `tmp[0] = new SomeOtherPoint()` and it will only fail at runtime. Generics don't have that problem: if writing to an element compiles, it won't fail because of a type mis-match at runtime. So the constraints imposed by `Span<T>` are necessarily a bit stricter that array variance allows. In order to ensure that `pointsSpan[0] = ...` doesn't fail at runtime because of a type mis-match, `Span<T>` needs to ensure that `T` is actually the same as the array's element type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of type safety. As pointed by @canton7 `Span<T>` have check against type, while `ReadOnlySpan<T>` doesn't. First one is mutable and it's possible to assign some value to it. As long value have same type, everything is ok, but if value have different type (e.g. `((object[])new string[1])[0] = 1`) array assignment throws `ArrayTypeMismatchException` so it won't be possible to have values of different types inside array.

`Span<T>` does this check at instantiation time. I don't know motivation behind this, maybe it's performance.

`ReadOnlySpan<T>` doesn't need this check since it's not mutable.

You can read more about array casting in chapter 16 "Arrays" in Clr via C# by Jeffrey Richter

Comment: `Span<T>` does this because the behaviour of all other generic collections is that assignment of an element won't fail at runtime because of a type mis-match: it's the expected behaviour. In order to behave in the same way as all other generic types, the only thing that `Span<T>` can do is to do a runtime check at instantiation

Comment: I thought compiler/runtime would know that .AsSpan() is being assigned to a ROS and allow it..

Comment: Why? You're telling it to create a `Span<T>`, then telling it to create a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` from that. Neither the compiler nor runtime can optimize that out, not least because doing so would cause a change in behaviour (in that it wouldn't throw that exception)

Comment: (Note that you can pass `points` directly to `Bar`, and the compiler will insert the right implicit conversion to `ReadOnlySpan<T>`)

Comment: `AsSpan` creates `Span<T>` that then converted via implicit cast to `ReadOnlySpan`. This can't be optimized in safe way